# How can I fine-tune my tile pattern to make it seamless?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I'd like to create a seamless pattern from the image below:

[image: leather]

I can cut out a rectangle and attempt to tile it but it doesn't quite line up:

[image: pattern]

I know photomerge works really well for creating panoramas but I was wondering if there is a similar tool that works on layers instead of files? Failing that, what other ways could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is to work with the outer edges of the image so they wrap around. One way is to take your tile and use the `Offset` filter (under the  <kbd>Filter > Other</kbd>  menu) and offset it by half the tile's pixel dimensions.

Once you do this, you can use your clone and touch up tools to eliminate the seams. and either use it as-is or offset it again by half.